# Linq to sql code for contains

Tags: c#, wcf, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the below code for reading data from sql(linq to sql)

For strSkillchk I may pass single value or more than 1 value based on the value provided I need the output

```
 string[] strSkillchk = new string[] {"10,11"};
 var getskilldim = (from tblskilldim in Skill_Dimensions
 where tblskilldim.Status == true && strSkillchk.Contains(tblskilldim.SkillSetId.ToString())
         select new Class
         {
             SkillDimenId = tblskilldim.SkillDimenId,
             SkillDimenName = tblskilldim.SkillDimenName
         }).ToList();
```

My sql table looks like

```
SkillDimenId    SkillDimenName   SkillSetId
  1                 Dimen1          10,11
  2                 Dimen2          11
  3                 Dimen3          10
```

But When I execute the above query it gives me only row 2 & 3
But I want the follwing output,

```
SkillDimenId      SkillDimenName      SkillSetId
  1                 Dimen1              10
  1                 Dimen1              11
  2                 Dimen2              11
  3                 Dimen3              10
```

Can any 1 help me fix this problem for linq to sql c#

Answer (score 2):

What you would need to do is to change

```
strSkillchk.Contains(tblskilldim.SkillSetId.ToString())
```

to

```
tblskilldim.SkillSetId.Split(',').Any(x=>strSkillchk.Contains(x))
```

but I sincerely doubt that liq to sql will handle such request and even then it would return

```
  1                 Dimen1          10,11
  2                 Dimen2          11
  3                 Dimen3          10
```

What is wrong with your database is that you have many to many mapping done by concatenation of ids. Such relation is usually done by introduction of third table that contains only Id from the two other. In such case your query would be much easier.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. It gives sql does not have support to the code error. I would take an idea of yours that I will create a third table where I map the Ids. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

hello i was able to get output similar to this

```
  1                 Dimen1          10,11
  2                 Dimen2          11
  3                 Dimen3          10
```

using below code, hope it will help you

```
    public class SKillIDDemo
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SkillSetID { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<SKillIDDemo> demos = new List<SKillIDDemo>();

            demos.Add(new SKillIDDemo() { ID = 1, Name = "demo1", SkillSetID = "10,1" });
            demos.Add(new SKillIDDemo() { ID = 2, Name = "demo2", SkillSetID = "10" });
            demos.Add(new SKillIDDemo() { ID = 3, Name = "demo3", SkillSetID = "1" });
            demos.Add(new SKillIDDemo() { ID = 4, Name = "demo4", SkillSetID = "12" });

            string[] skillset = { "10","1" };

            var testme =   demos.Where(x=> skillset.Any(a=> x.SkillSetID.Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Contains(a))).ToList();

            testme.ForEach(g=> Console.WriteLine(g.Name));  

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```